# MVC View Imports Page Doesnt Exist

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, view, import

I'm new at .net core and trying to learn it. When i try to Views>Right click>Add new Item - I Can't find "MVC View Imports Page" at List, it doesn't exist. How to fix it?

Comment: I am unsure what tutorial you are trying to follow, but this option hasn't existed for me for a while in VS2017 (preview version if that matters). You can however just `Add` -> `New Item` -> `_ViewImports.cshtml`. This file goes in the base view directory, e.g. `~/me/SomeProject/Views/_ViewImports.cshtml`.

Comment: i can't reach _ViewImports.cshtml it doesnt exist at new item's list

Answer (score 1):

I think it's too late, but as I had the same problem, I'll share the "solution".

In Visual Studio 2017 15.6 it was renamed to "Razor View Imports"